# Get restful api con Flurl

Tags: c#, nodejs, http-get

Tengo mi servicio el cual contiene la ruta http://localhost:3000/users/getbyid/4 y la ruta http://localhost:3000/users/getall
la primera ruta me recupera de mi bd el usuario con id = 4
y me devuelve un objeto json con los valores de dicho usuario.

Al hacer la peticion por medio de postman este es el resultado: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda ruta me recupera todos los usarios en mi bd.

Ahora en C# tengo estas funciones

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = GetAll().Result;
    Person person = GetById().Result;
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async Task<Person> GetById() {
    Person p = new Person();
    try {
        p = await url.AppendPathSegment(string.Format("getbyid/{0}", 4)).GetJsonAsync<Person>();
        p.Message = "200";
        return p;
    } catch (FlurlHttpException ex) {
        p.Message = ex.Call.HttpStatus.ToString();
    }
    return p;
}

private static async Task<List<Person>> GetAll() {
    return await url.AppendPathSegment("getall").GetJsonAsync<List<Person>>();
}
```

Al ejecutar la aplicacion y ver los datos de persons y person vemos que el getall me devuelve los datos del usuario 4 pero getbyid no lo hace

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi servicio NodeJs estas son las 2 funciones a las que se llama para hacer el getall y el getbyid

```
export const GetAllUsers = async (req:Request, res:Response): Promise<Response> => {
    const response:QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
    return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
}

export const GetUserById = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const response : QueryResult = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1 AND logicaldelete = FALSE", [id]);
    if (response.rowCount > 0) {
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
    } else {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User Not Exist'            
        }); 
    }

}
```

Este es el mensaje de error en la funcion getbyid de C#: 
Response could not be deserialized to JSON: GET http://localhost:3000/users/getbyid/4

Porque sucede ese error?

Comment: `return res.status(200).json(response.rows);` en esta linea, podrías indicar el contenido de `response.rows`?

Comment: Te dice que no puede deserealizar porque tenes distinto los nombres de las propiedades en tu servicio cuando recibis no coincide. Respeta mayusculas y minusculas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre el problema. Mi servicio devuelve una lista con el objeto dentro y en mi codigo C# trataba de guardar en un objeto y no en una lista del objeto.
Para resolverlo simplemente edite la funcion getbyid del servicio quedando de la siguiente mantera:

```
export const GetUserById = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const response : QueryResult = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1 AND logicaldelete = FALSE", [id]);
    if (response.rowCount > 0) {
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows[0]);
    } else {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User Not Exist'            
        }); 
    }

}
```

Como veran el unico cambio es que le agregue [0] en el response.rows
esto hace que ahora el json sea solo un objeto y no una lista, solucionando asi el problema.
Muchas gracias.